# tinyMCE does not work with Active Admin in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, activeadmin, srware-iron

I used this [guide](http://code.davemorro.com/post/7919233521/hacking-activeadmin-adding-a-javascript-text-editor) to integrate tinyMCE into Active Admin textarea elements.

I did:

Download tinyMCE of latest version (tinymce_3.5.6.zip) and put tiny_mce folder to my puplic/javascripts folder.

Added app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  mode : "textareas",
  theme : "advanced",
  theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold, italic, underline, strikethrough, |, bullist, numlist, blockquote, |, undo, redo, |, link, unlink, code",
  theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
  theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
  theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "center",
  theme_advanced_resizing : false
});
```

Edited config/initializers/active_admin.rb:

```
#...
  config.register_javascript '/javascripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
  config.register_javascript 'active_admin.js'
end
```

This results in no tinyMCE integrated in active admin in chrome.
Output from the Chrome console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined active_admin.js:1
  (anonymous function) active_admin.js:1
Load jQuery first! tiny_mce.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'extend' tiny_mce.js:1
c.create tiny_mce.js:1
  (anonymous function) tiny_mce.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'init' active_admin.js:1
  (anonymous function) active_admin.js:1
```

Though tinyMCE works good in Safari and SRWare Iron. But SRWare Iron console still has some errors in console output:

```
active_admin.js:1Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
(anonymous function)active_admin.js:1
```

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem via renaming `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js` to `app/assets/javascripts/active_admin_custom.js`.

I come to this because found in the generated html page with textarea two javascripts with `active_admin.js` name... That seemed to be the conflict.